# The .insert() function is not working for my entry box

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am writing a function that takes an entry box widget as a parameter, configures the entry box (change the colour of  text) and then inserts some text into the entry box. Evrythig works fine except the text does not appear into the entry box.

The Function is below:

```
def entry_error(self, entry):
        entry.delete(0, tk.END)
        entry.config(fg = "red")
        entry.insert(0, "Data Invalid!")
```

The call to the function is:

```
if len(firstName) == 0: # If no data is entered for the first name
            dataValid = False # The data is invalid
            self.entry_error(self.firstNameEntry) ### <-- CALL TO FUNCTION ###
```

The full code is:

*** The Function is under the 'registerPage' class ***

```
'''
Variable Name = variableName
Function Name = function_name
'''

import string # Importing the string module
import random # Importing the random module
import sqlite3 # Importing sqlite3
import tkinter as tk # Importing the tkinter module to create a GUI
from tkinter import messagebox # Importing the messagebox class from the tkinter module
from tkinter import filedialog # Importing the filedialog class from the tkinter module
from shutil import copyfile # Importing the copyfile class from the shutil module



# Class To Create The Main Window #
class window(tk.Tk): # Defining the class (window) which inherits the properties of the tkinter class Tk
    def __init__(self): # Defining the initial function that runs every time an instance of this class is made
        tk.Tk.__init__(self) # Running the __init__() function of the Tk class to create the new window

        self.screenWidth = self.winfo_screenwidth() # Sets the variable screenWidth to the width of the users screen
        self.screenHeight = self.winfo_screenheight() # Sets the variable screenHeight to the height of the users screen

        self.geometry("%sx%s" % (self.screenWidth, self.screenHeight)) # Sets the width and height of the main window to the width and height of the users screen
        self.overrideredirect(1) # Removes the border from the window

        self.existingFrames = {} # Creating a dictionay to store the frames that currently exist

        ''' All New Frame classes need to be added to the list below '''
        self.frameNames = [loginPage, registerPage, termsOfServicePage] # Creating a lsit of names of all the frames linked to this class

        for frameName in self.frameNames: # Iterating through the list of names of frames
            self.existingFrames[frameName] = frameName(self) # Creating a new element in the dictionary where the frame name is the key and the frame pointer is the value
            self.existingFrames[frameName].grid(row = 0, column = 0) # Adding the frame to the windows grid

        self.existingFrames[loginPage].lift() # Bringing the login screen to the top so that it is visible by the user

    def show_frame(self, frameToShow): # Creating a function in the class that takes the name of the frame to display
        frame = self.existingFrames[frameToShow] # Gets the value from the dictionary of the frame that is passed through as frameToShow
        frame.lift() # Raises the frame to the top so that it is visible by the user

    def close_window(self): # Function to close the window when called
        closeWindow = messagebox.askyesno("Close Window?", "Are you sure you want to close the window?\nAll unsaved data will be lost!") # Asks the user if they definitely want to close the window and stores the result under the variable closeWindow
        if closeWindow == True: # If the user answeres yes
            self.destroy() # The window gets destroyed
            exit() # The program is exited


# Class To Create The Login Page #
class loginPage(tk.Frame): # Defining the class (loginPage) which inherits the properties of the tkinter Frame class
    def __init__(self, parentClass): # Defining the initial function that runs every time an instance of this class is made
        self.parentClass = parentClass # Creating a variable to store the pointer to the parent class that can be used by all function in this class

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, self.parentClass, width = self.parentClass.screenWidth, height = self.parentClass.screenHeight) # Creates a Frame inside the main window passed through as rootWidnow

        self.exitButton = tk.Button(self, text = "X", fg = "red", font = ("", 10), command = self.parentClass.close_window) # Creates an exit button in the Frame with the main window's close_windwo() command
        self.exitButton.place(anchor = tk.NE, x = self.parentClass.screenWidth, y = 0) # Places the exit button in the top right corner of the frame


        self.usernamelabel = tk.Label(self, text = "Username:", font = ("Cooper Black", 15)) # Creating a label to instruct the user to enter their username
        self.usernamelabel.place(anchor = tk.CENTER, x = (self.parentClass.screenWidth / 5) * 2, y = (self.parentClass.screenHeight / 12) * 5) # Placing the label in the frame

        self.passwordlabel = tk.Label(self, text = "Password:", font = ("Cooper Black", 15)) # Creating a label to instruct the user to enter their password
        self.passwordlabel.place(anchor = tk.CENTER, x = (self.parentClass.screenWidth / 5) * 2, y = (self.parentClass.screenHeight / 12) * 6) # Placing the label in the frame

        self.usernameEntry = tk.Entry(self, font = ("", 12)) # Creating an entry for the user to enter their username
        self.usernameEntry.place(anchor = tk.CENTER, x = (self.parentClass.screenWidth / 5) * 3, y = (self.parentClass.screenHeight / 12) * 5) # Placing the entry next to usernamelabel in the frame

        self.passwordEntry = tk.Entry(self, font = ("", 12), show = "*") # Creating an entry for the user to enter their password (A * will be shown instead of plain text for security)
        self.passwordEntry.place(anchor = tk.CENTER, x = (self.parentClass.screenWidth / 5) * 3, y = (self.parentClass.screenHeight / 12) * 6) # Placing the entry next to passowrdlabel in the frame

        self.loginButton = tk.Button(self, text = "Login", font = ("Cooper Black", 17), command = self.submit_data) # Creating a button for the user to submit their login details
        self.loginButton.place(anchor = tk.CENTER, x = (self.parentClass.screenWidth / 2), y = (self.parentClass.screenHeight / 12) * 7) # Placing the button in the frame

        self.newAccountButton = tk.Button(self, text = "Dont Have An Account!", font = ("Cooper Black", 13), command = self.no_account) # Creating a button for the user to go to the screen to register a new account
        self.newAccountButton.place(anchor = tk.CENTER, x = (self.parentClass.screenWidth / 2), y = (self.parentClass.screenHeight / 12) * 8) # Placing the button in the frame

    def submit_data(self): # Creating a function to submit the users login details (parameters: the entries used for the username and password)
        username = self.usernameEntry.get() # geting the username from the username entry
        password = self.passwordEntry.get() # getting the password from the passoword entry

        self.usernameEntry.delete(0, tk.END) # Deleting the text in the entry
        self.passwordEntry.delete(0, tk.END) # Deleting the text in the entry

        # VALIDATE DATA #

    def no_account(self): # Creating a function to take the user to the register screen if they do not have an account
        self.usernameEntry.delete(0, tk.END) # Deleting the text in the entry
        self.passwordEntry.delete(0, tk.END) # Deleting the text in the entry

        self.parentClass.show_frame(registerPage) # Switches the screen visible by the user to the register screen



# Class To Create The Register Page #
class registerPage(tk.Frame): # Defining the class (registerPage) which inherits the properties of the tkinter Frame class
    def __init__(self, parentClass): # Defining the initial function that runs every time an instance of this class is made
        self.parentClass = parentClass # Creating a variable to store the pointer to the parent class that can be used by all function in this class

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, self.parentClass, width = self.parentClass.screenWidth, height = self.parentClass.screenHeight) # Creates a Frame inside the main window passed through as rootWidnow

        self.exitButton = tk.Button(self, text = "X", fg = "red", font = ("", 10), command = self.parentClass.close_window) # Creates an exit button in the Frame with the main window's close_windwo() command
        self.exitButton.place(anchor = tk.NE, x = self.parentClass.screenWidth, y = 0) # Places the exit button in the top right corner of the frame


        self.firstNameLabel = tk.Label(self, text = "First Name:", font = ("Cooper Black", 15)) # Creating a label to instruct the user to enter their first name
        self.firstNameLabel.place(anchor = tk.CENTER, x = (self.parentClass.screenWidth / 20) * 3, y = (self.parentClass.screenHeight / 9) * 1) # Placing the label in the frame

        self.firstNameEntry = tk.Entry(self, font = ("", 12)) # Creating an entry for the user to enter their first name
        self.firstNameEntry.place(anchor = tk.CENTER, x = (self.parentClass.screenWidth / 20) * 7, y = (self.parentClass.screenHeight / 9) * 1) # Placing the entry in the frame

        self.surnameLabel = tk.Label(self, text = "Surname:", font = ("Cooper Black", 15)) # Creating a label to instruct the user to enter their surname
        self.surnameLabel.place(anchor = tk.CENTER, x = (self.parentClass.screenWidth / 20) * 3, y = (self.parentClass.screenHeight / 9) * 2) # Placing the label in the frame

        self.surnameEntry = tk.Entry(self, font = ("", 12)) # Creating an entry for the user to enter their surname
        self.surnameEntry.place(anchor = tk.CENTER, x = (self.parentClass.screenWidth / 20) * 7, y = (self.parentClass.screenHeight / 9) * 2) # Placing the entry in the frame

        self.emailLabel = tk.Label(self, text = "Email:", font = ("Cooper Black", 15)) # Creating a label to instruct the user to enter their email
        self.emailLabel.place(anchor = tk.CENTER, x = (self.parentClass.screenWidth / 20) * 3, y = (self.parentClass.screenHeight / 9) * 3) # Placing the label in the frame#

        self.emailEntry = tk.Entry(self, font = ("", 12)) # Creating an entry for the user to enter their email
        self.emailEntry.place(anchor = tk.CENTER, x = (self.parentClass.screenWidth / 20) * 7, y = (self.parentClass.screenHeight / 9) * 3) # Placing the entry in the frame

        self.confirmEmailLabel = tk.Label(self, text = "Confirm Email:", font = ("Cooper Black", 15)) # Creating a label to instruct the user to enter their email
        self.confirmEmailLabel.place(anchor = tk.CENTER, x = (self.parentClass.screenWidth / 20) * 3, y = (self.parentClass.screenHeight / 9) * 4) # Placing the label in the frame

        self.confirmEmailEntry = tk.Entry(self, font = ("", 12)) # Creating an entry for the user to enter their confirm email
        self.confirmEmailEntry.place(anchor = tk.CENTER, x = (self.parentClass.screenWidth / 20) * 7, y = (self.parentClass.screenHeight / 9) * 4) # Placing the entry in the frame

        self.usernameLabel = tk.Label(self, text = "Username:", font = ("Cooper Black", 15)) # Creating a label to instruct the user to enter their first name
        self.usernameLabel.place(anchor = tk.CENTER, x = (self.parentClass.screenWidth / 20) * 13, y = (self.parentClass.screenHeight / 9) * 1) # Placing the label in the frame

        self.usernameEntry = tk.Entry(self, font = ("", 12)) # Creating an entry for the user to enter their first name
        self.usernameEntry.place(anchor = tk.CENTER, x = (self.parentClass.screenWidth / 20) * 17, y = (self.parentClass.screenHeight / 9) * 1) # Placing the entry in the frame

        self.passwordLabel = tk.Label(self, text = "Password:", font = ("Cooper Black", 15)) # Creating a label to instruct the user to enter their surname
        self.passwordLabel.place(anchor = tk.CENTER, x = (self.parentClass.screenWidth / 20) * 13, y = (self.parentClass.screenHeight / 9) * 2) # Placing the label in the frame

        self.passwordEntry = tk.Entry(self, font = ("", 12), show = "*") # Creating an entry for the user to enter their surname
        self.passwordEntry.place(anchor = tk.CENTER, x = (self.parentClass.screenWidth / 20) * 17, y = (self.parentClass.screenHeight / 9) * 2) # Placing the entry in the frame

        self.confirmPasswordLabel = tk.Label(self, text = "Confirm Password:", font = ("Cooper Black", 15)) # Creating a label to instruct the user to enter their email
        self.confirmPasswordLabel.place(anchor = tk.CENTER, x = (self.parentClass.screenWidth / 20) * 13, y = (self.parentClass.screenHeight / 9) * 3) # Placing the label in the frame#

        self.confirmPasswordEntry = tk.Entry(self, font = ("", 12), show = "*") # Creating an entry for the user to enter their email
        self.confirmPasswordEntry.place(anchor = tk.CENTER, x = (self.parentClass.screenWidth / 20) * 17, y = (self.parentClass.screenHeight / 9) * 3) # Placing the entry in the frame

        self.termsOfServiceVar = tk.IntVar() # Creating an Integer variable to store the status of the terms of service check button
        self.termsOfServiceCheckButton = tk.Checkbutton(self, text = "I agree to the terms of service", variable = self.termsOfServiceVar) # Creating a check button for the user to accept the terms of service
        self.termsOfServiceCheckButton.place(anchor = tk.CENTER, x = (self.parentClass.screenWidth / 20) * 13, y = (self.parentClass.screenHeight / 9) * 4) # Places the check button in the frame
        self.termsOfServiceCheckButton.bind("<Button 1>", self.show_terms_of_service) # Runs the show_terms_of_service function when the check button is clicked

        self.recieveEmailsVar = tk.IntVar() # Creating an Integer variable to store the status of the email preference check button
        self.recieveEmailsCheckButton = tk.Checkbutton(self, text = "I agree to recieve promotional emails", variable = self.recieveEmailsVar) # Creates a check button for the user to agree to recieve promotinal emails
        self.recieveEmailsCheckButton.place(anchor = tk.CENTER, x = (self.parentClass.screenWidth / 20) * 17.5, y = (self.parentClass.screenHeight / 9) * 4) # Places the check button in the frame

        self.registerButton = tk.Button(self, text = "Register", font = ("Cooper Black", 17), command = self.submit_data) # Creating a button for the user to submit their data
        self.registerButton.place(anchor = tk.CENTER, x = (self.parentClass.screenWidth / 20) * 10, y = (self.parentClass.screenHeight / 9) * 5.25)

        self.hasAccountButton = tk.Button(self, text = "Already Have An Account!", font = ("Cooper Black", 13), command = self.has_account) # Creating a button for the user to go to the login screen
        self.hasAccountButton.place(anchor = tk.CENTER, x = (self.parentClass.screenWidth / 20) * 10, y = (self.parentClass.screenHeight / 9) * 6) # Placing the button in the frame

        self.dividerLine = tk.Label(self, text = "_" * self.parentClass.screenWidth, font = ("Cooper Black", 15)) # Creating a line to divide the screen into sections
        self.dividerLine.place(anchor = tk.CENTER, x = (self.parentClass.screenWidth / 20) * 10, y = (self.parentClass.screenHeight / 9) * 7) # Placing the label in the frame

        self.loginAsGuestButton = tk.Button(self, text = "Continue As Guest", font = ("Cooper Black", 13), command = self.login_as_guest) # Creating a button for the user to go to sign in as a guest
        self.loginAsGuestButton.place(anchor = tk.CENTER, x = (self.parentClass.screenWidth / 20) * 10, y = (self.parentClass.screenHeight / 9) * 8) # Placing the button in the frame

    def empty_entries(self): # Creating a function to empty the data from the etnry boxes
        entries = [self.firstNameEntry, self.surnameEntry, self.emailEntry, self.confirmEmailEntry, self.usernameEntry, self.passwordEntry, self.confirmPasswordEntry] # List of entries in the register screen
        for entry in entries: # Iterates through the list of entries
            entry.delete(0, tk.END) # Deletes the text in the entry
        self.termsOfServiceVar.set(0) # Resetting the check button
        self.recieveEmailsVar.set(0) # Resetting the check button

    def entry_error(self, entry):
        entry.delete(0, tk.END)
        entry.config(fg = "red")
        entry.insert(0, "Data Invalid!")
        entry.bind("<Button 1>")#, lambda event: self.remove_entry_error(entry))

    def remove_entry_error(self, entry):
        entry.delete(0, tk.END)
        entry.config(fg = "black")
        entry.unbind("<Button 1>")

    def has_account(self):
        self.empty_entries()
        self.parentClass.show_frame(loginPage) # Switches the screen visible by the user to the login screen

    def submit_data(self):
        firstName = self.firstNameEntry.get() # getting the data from the entry box and storing it under a variable
        surname = self.surnameEntry.get() # getting the data from the entry box and storing it under a variable
        email = self.emailEntry.get() # getting the data from the entry box and storing it under a variable
        confirmEmail = self.confirmEmailEntry.get() # getting the data from the entry box and storing it under a variable
        username = self.usernameEntry.get() # getting the data from the entry box and storing it under a variable
        password = self.passwordEntry.get() # getting the data from the entry box and storing it under a variable
        confirmPassword = self.confirmPasswordEntry.get() # getting the data from the entry box and storing it under a variable
        termsOfServiceStatus = self.termsOfServiceVar.get() # getting the data from the check button and storing it under a variable
        recieveEmailsStatus = self.recieveEmailsVar.get() # getting the data from the check button and storing it under a variable

        # Validating Data #
        dataValid = True # Variable to store whether or not the data is valid. Data stays valid untill found invalid

        if len(firstName) == 0: # If no data is entered for the first name
            dataValid = False # The data is invalid
            self.entry_error(self.firstNameEntry) # Runs the function to display an error in the data to the user

        if len(surname) == 0: # If no data is entered for the surname
            dataValid = False # The data is invalid

        if "@" not in email or "." not in email: # If the email does not contain both an '@' and a '.'
            dataValid = False # The data is invalid

        if confirmEmail != email: # If both emails do not match
            dataValid = False # The data is invalid

        if " " in username: # If the username contains a space
            dataValid = False # the data is invalid

        if len(password) < 8: # If the password is less than 8 characters
            dataValid = False # The data is invalid
        else:
            uppercase = False # Variable to store if the password contains an uppercase letter
            lowercase = False # Variable to store if the password contains an lowercase letter
            punctuation = False # Variable to store if the password contains a special character
            digit = False # Variable to store if the password contains a digit
            for char in password: # Iterates through each character in the password
                if char in string.ascii_uppercase: # If the character is an uppercase letter
                    uppercase = True # The uppercase variable is true
                elif char in string.ascii_lowercase: # If the character is a lowercase letter
                    lowercase = True # The lowercase variable is true
                elif char in string.punctuation: # If the character is a special character
                    punctuation = True # The punctuation variable is true
                elif char in string.digits: # If the character is a digit
                    digit = True # The digit variable is true
            if uppercase == False or lowercase == False or punctuation == False or digit == False: # If any of the 4 variables are False
                dataValid = False # The data is invalid

        if confirmPassword != password: # If the two passwords dont match
            dataValid = False # The data is invalid

        self.empty_entries()

    def login_as_guest(self):
        pass

    def show_terms_of_service(self, *args): # Function to show the terms of service screen
        self.termsOfServiceCheckButton.unbind("<Button 1>") # Unbinds Button 1 from the widget
        self.parentClass.show_frame(termsOfServicePage) # Calls the function to display the terms of service screen

# Class To Create The Terms Of Service Page #
class termsOfServicePage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parentClass):
        self.parentClass = parentClass

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, self.parentClass, width = self.parentClass.screenWidth, height = self.parentClass.screenHeight)

        self.exitButton = tk.Button(self, text = "X", fg = "red", font = ("", 10), command = lambda: self.exit_screen(False))
        self.exitButton.place(anchor = tk.NE, x = self.parentClass.screenWidth, y = 0)

        self.titleLabel = tk.Label(self, text = "Terms Of Service", font = ("Cooper Black", 20))
        self.titleLabel.place(anchor = tk.CENTER, x = (self.parentClass.screenWidth / 2), y = (self.parentClass.screenHeight / 11) * 1)

        self.acceptButton = tk.Button(self, text = "Accept Terms Of Service", font = ("Cooper Black", 17), command = lambda: self.exit_screen(True))
        self.acceptButton.place(anchor = tk.CENTER, x = (self.parentClass.screenWidth / 2), y = (self.parentClass.screenHeight / 11) * 10)

    def exit_screen(self, status):
        if status == True:
            self.parentClass.existingFrames[registerPage].termsOfServiceVar.set(1)
        else:
            self.parentClass.existingFrames[registerPage].termsOfServiceVar.set(0)

        self.parentClass.show_frame(registerPage)

mainWindow = window() # Creating an instance of the window class
mainWindow.mainloop() # Calling the mainloop function on mainWindow to allow the user to interact with the window and to allow events to be responded to
```

Comment: Please try to reduce your code down to a [mcve]. We really only need one entry, the function you are having trouble with, and enough code to make it run.

Comment: I have tried to simplify it however upon doing so, the issue gets solved. I cannot work out how this is the case as I only get the issue when the above code is present.

Comment: After I have inserted the text I have tried to print the contents of the entry with the .get() function and the data is printed so the insert is working but the text is not showing in the entry

Comment: Please try again. I can’t believe that the only way to reproduce this requires a dozen entry widgets, labels, and intvars,  plus dozens of lines of validation code.